# Sphinx When Restart/Stop searchd.pid is deleted

Tags: centos, sphinx

I just install Sphinx version sphinx-2.2.11-1.rhel7.x86_64 on Centos7.3

So i success to install it and index the database and when i start it first time the Sphinx is starting but when i try to use service searchd stop or service searchd restart everytime the searchd.pid is auto deleted but never created again so the sphinx can't start again because of the error

```
[root@ns510209 log]# service searchd start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  searchd.service
Job for searchd.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status searchd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Any suggestion how i can fix this issue im trying for few days to find a way but still no luck ...

Comment: did you check searchd log?

Comment: [Fri Jul  7 03:38:41.500 2017] [4325] FATAL: failed to create pid file '/home/www/websites/_sphinx/web/log/searchd.pid': Permission denied but i give it access to sphinx user and 777 chmod to the folder but looks like something is wrong ...

Comment: Check if you can do this manually: `sudo -u sphinx touch /home/www/websites/_sphinx/web/log/searchd.pid`.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue. The root cause is that searchd cannot write the binlog file due to incorrect metadata in the following folder:

```
    # ls -al /var/lib/sphinx/
    total 23580
    drwxr-xr-x  2 sphinx sphinx     4096 Jul  9 16:52 .
    drwxr-xr-x 33 root   root       4096 Mar 12 14:18 ..
    -rw-------  1 sphinx sphinx        8 Jul  9 16:47 binlog.001
    -rw-------  1 sphinx sphinx        8 Jul  9 16:52 binlog.002
    -rw-------  1 sphinx sphinx        0 Jul  9 16:52 binlog.lock
    -rw-------  1 sphinx sphinx       12 Jul  9 16:52 binlog.meta
    -rw-------  1 sphinx sphinx        0 Jun 21 18:53 doc.old.spl
    -rw-r--r--  1 sphinx sphinx        0 Jul  9 16:52 doc.spa
```

Move all files, except for doc.* (or whatever prefix is used), from this folder. Then start the service:

```
    # systemctl start searchd
    # systemctl status searchd
    ● searchd.service - SphinxSearch Search Engine
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/searchd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-07-09 16:52:43 MSK; 6min ago
      Process: 1690 ExecStart=/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 1687 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown sphinx.sphinx /var/run/sphinx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 1684 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/sphinx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 1693 (searchd)
       CGroup: /system.slice/searchd.service
               ├─1692 /usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf
               └─1693 /usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf
```